# Webscraping with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I have been working on a project to scrape the schedule from an amateur hockey site and export it to csv in a format that is acceptable to upload into the Sports Engine application. I have managed to get the data I want in a text only format but now need to figure out how to convert it so it can be exported to csv.

Here is a sample output of the script, shortened for brevity.

**AL1602 · Nov 6 · Atom A League · FVC Flight 3FINALMSA Arena · Abbotsford, BCLANGLEY MHA ATOM A4 EAGLES2 - 6ABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS AL1607 · Nov 10 · Atom A League · FVC Flight 3FINALMission Leisure Centre · North · Mission, BCTime change due to ice conflict CSABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS5 - 4MISSION MHA ATOM A2**

Here is a sample output of the script but just using `print(tables)` to show the formatting and not just printing out the text.

`[<tr class="gamelist-row"><td class="game-details"><div class="game-meta text-muted">AL1602 · Nov 6<a class="text-muted" href="/leagues/786?scheduleId=1265&amp;groupId=5" title="Atom A League · FVC Flight 3"> · Atom A League · FVC Flight 3</a></div><div class="game-time">FINAL</div><div class="game-arena">MSA Arena<span class="text-muted"> · Abbotsford, BC</span></div></td><td><div class="game-matchup"><a class="team-link" href="/teams/4688?scheduleId=1265&amp;groupId=5"><div class="d-flex flex-row" style="min-width: 125px;"><div class="pr-2"><div alt="LANGLEY MHA ATOM A4 EAGLES" class="team-logo" style='background-image: url("https://s3-ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/hisports-logos/1537488764672.png");'></div></div><div class="d-flex flex-fill flex-column justify-content-center"><span class="team-name text-uppercase">LANGLEY MHA ATOM A4 EAGLES</span></div></div></a><div class="game-result score"><div class="result result-loss">2</div><span class="text-muted"> - </span><div class="result result-win">6</div></div><a class="team-link" href="/teams/4326?scheduleId=1265&amp;groupId=5"><div class="d-flex flex-row flex-row-reverse" style="min-width: 125px;"><div class="pl-2"><div alt="ABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS" class="team-logo" style='background-image: url("https://s3-ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/hisports-logos/1538567502609.jpg");'></div></div><div class="d-flex flex-fill flex-column justify-content-center"><span class="team-name text-uppercase text-right">ABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS</span></div></div></a></div></td></tr>, <tr class="gamelist-row"><td class="game-details"><div class="game-meta text-muted">AL1607`

Below is the script.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#launch url
url = "https://games.pcaha.ca/teams/4326"

#create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

#After opening the url above, Selenium finds the table with the schedule
games = driver.find_elements_by_id("table-responsive")

#Selenium hands the page source to Beautiful Soup
soupsource=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
soupsource.prettify()

#Beautiful Soup grabs the class gamelist-row
tables = soupsource.find_all("tr", class_="gamelist-row")

# prints out the text only
for x in tables:
    print(x.text)
```

Comment: Can you show sample expected result?

Comment: Can you post the output of the script ?

Comment: @Marco Here is a sample output of the script, shortened for brevity. **AL1602 · Nov 6 · Atom A League · FVC Flight 3FINALMSA Arena · Abbotsford, BCLANGLEY MHA ATOM A4 EAGLES2 - 6ABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS
AL1607 · Nov 10 · Atom A League · FVC Flight 3FINALMission Leisure Centre · North · Mission, BCTime change due to ice conflict CSABBOTSFORD ATOM A2 HAWKS5 - 4MISSION MHA ATOM A2**

Comment: @wedge22 it is not just for me, you can put it in the post.. then looking from here are fields separated by tabs and lines separated by CR ?

Comment: @Marco I have added more information to my original post that should answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
fieldnames = ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'field1': 'John Smith', 'field2': 'Accounting','field3': 'November'})
```

Try this little snippet out for writing to a csv file. Modify it to fit your needs!